# how to print variable value in generate your project ( gyp )

Tags: gyp

I am new to gyp & i googled a lot, but i am not getting any information regarding printing variable value in **.gyp** or **.gypi** file. I tried using echo, but that did not worked for me.

so, my question is very simple : How to print variable in gyp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an action to print the variables:

```
{
    "variables": {
        "BUILD_TESTS": "false",
    },
    "targets": [
        {
        "target_name": "my_target",
        'actions': [
            {
                'action_name': 'print_variables',
                'action': [ 'echo', 'BUILD_TESTS: <(BUILD_TESTS) | BASE_DIR: <(BASE_DIR)', ],

                'inputs': [],
                'outputs': [ "src/some_file.cc" ],
            }
        ],
        ...
        }
    ]
}
```

Make sure that "outputs" points to a file that is referenced in your "sources", even though you don't actually create that file. Otherwise the action won't run and you will not see any output.

Comment: I added the targets according to your instruction, but it didn't work. I guess "my_target" needs to be added as a dependency somewhere!?